# LibGDX: make stage accept only one touch at a time

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I have my main menu, the game store, and game controls use stages basically for buttons functionality. Problem is, stage takes in multiple finger inputs. This is a problem for me because I have a in game store, so it's not safe to allow the user to press two items, then leg go and buy them at the same time (I don't want the money integer being screwed up if two purchase actions try to subtract from it at the same time).

Question: Is there an easy way to force Stage to only take one finger input? I only need it for the buttons...

Or will I have to make the purchase actions atomic?
Or add another input listener to each button that disables all the other buttons on touchDown(), and enables them on touchUp()?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you detect if more than one buttons have been pressed and warn the user that only one can be accepted, or disable the others as one was pressed?

Comment: I should be able to do that as I proposed here: "Or add another input listener to each button that disables all the other buttons on touchDown(), and enables them on touchUp()?" There are couple of problems with that though: 1) I'd have to make the buttons statics since I'm letting the buttons know about each other, so it become tightly coupled in my opinion. 2) A lot of repetitive code.

Comment: I just checked a whole bunch of Android libGDX games, a lot of them have this bug, though not many have stores so it doesn't break the games. Looks like one of the games might be using grouped buttons which makes it focus on the last touch, but still very glichy.

Comment: Can't you just ignore any pointer index that is greater than zero?

Comment: Because that is done for me in the stage class behind the scenes, I'd have to change some parts of the stage class to implement that if it's not already (which I don't think it is).